How to extract metrics of number of busy application instances based on logFmt log entries with different start/end contens in Grafana + Loki
I'm using Grafana + Loki for monitoring operation of an application that generates logs in logFmt format. The application outputs log entries with different text patterns when it starts and ends processing a request, let's say, msg="Started processing request" and msg="Completed processing request". An instance is considered busy for the time interval between these two messages.
Logs from several application instances running in parallel are collected and aggregated to same Loki instance. Each application instance decorates its log entries with a unique per-instance instance.id label.
Metrics I need to collect and visualise in time series are the number of busy instances per second and the intervals of time during which each instance was busy processing a request.
How can I create the queries that return the busy intervals for each application instance, and the number of busy application instances per second?
BR

Not that with what you want to do is something wrong, but it would be way way easier to do with actual metrics.

Regarding the problem at hand: I'd tackle it like this: based on msg add label with value 0/1, use last_over_time unwrapping that label, sum result.

I know this is not the best way, but a workaround until specific metrics are introduced later.
How can I add fields with fixed values (+1/-1), +1 when the processing start message is found, -1 when the processing end message is found?

IMO you need 2 queries. (1. cumulative sum of log count "started") - (2. cumulative sum of log count "completed"). Of course that's theory, so check LogQL how can you write that in reality.
